# As an argument of a function, when does a variable name need to be quoted?

Tags: vimscript, variables

If I define the variable `foo` like this:

```
:let foo = '~/Desktop'
```

And I want to check the length of the string it contains, then I can type:

```
:echo strlen(foo)
```

The output is 9, which is right.
If I had typed `:echo strlen('foo')`, the output would have been 3, because Vim would have calculated the length of the string `'foo'` instead of the evaluation of the variable `foo`.

Next, I want to expand the filepath contained in `foo`.
The following command doesn't echo any message:

```
:echo glob('foo')
```

But the following does output something (`/home/username/Desktop`):

```
:echo glob(foo)
```

So, these 2 examples seem to show that if I want to pass the evaluation of a variable name as an argument to a function, I must not put quotes around it.

Now, if I want to check whether the variable `foo` exists and has been defined, and I type:

```
:if exists(foo) | echo "success!" | endif
```

There's no output. However, the following works:

```
:if exists('foo') | echo "success!" | endif
```

This time, it was different, as I needed to put quotes around `foo` for it to be evaluated by `exists()`.
Why do I need to use quotes with `exists()` but neither with `strlen()` nor with `glob()` ?

When do you need to put quotes around a variable name which is passed as an argument to a function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has to do with the nature of [`exists()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#exists%28%29):

```
Note that the argument must be a string, not the name of the
 variable itself.  For example: 
         exists(bufcount)
This doesn't check for existence of the "bufcount" variable,
 but gets the value of "bufcount", and checks if that exists.
```

Since `exists()` examines the contents of the argument, if you want to check if a variable named `foo` exists, you must pass it a string containing `foo`. You could have done the following just as well (after defining `foo`):

```
:let bar = 'foo'
:if exists(bar) | echo "success!" | endif
```

So, you need to quote the variable and make it a string, when you're interested in dealing with the variable itself, not its contents.

Comment: Ok, so when I said that `exists()` did not evaluate the variable, I was wrong. `exists()` is no different than `strlen()`, `glob()` or any other function.
No matter the function, Vim always evaluates the variable before sending the result to the function.
Usually this is what you want. But not with `exists()`, because usually you don't want to check whether the contents of a variable exists but whether the variable itself exists. So, the quotes are here to tell Vim: "don't evaluate the variable, leave it as it is".